# Android and Arduino Serial Communication USB

Tags: java, android, arduino, usb

I am working on a small Android app that would send a signal to an Arduino via USB and thus control a robot. Here is the code. With this app I can detect the Arduino board and also the vendor ID and all, but I don't know what needs to be initialized to send a serial signal to the Arduino board.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.lenovo.client;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.nfc.tech.IsoDep;
import android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic;
import android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight;
import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
import android.nfc.tech.NfcA;
import android.nfc.tech.NfcB;
import android.nfc.tech.NfcF;
import android.nfc.tech.NfcV;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.lenovo.client.UsbSerialDevice;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void Button(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    Button mButton;
    EditText mEdit;
    public String d;

    private final String[][] techList = new String[][]{
        new String[]{
            NfcA.class.getName(),
            NfcB.class.getName(),
            NfcF.class.getName(),
            NfcV.class.getName(),
            IsoDep.class.getName(),
            MifareClassic.class.getName(),
            MifareUltralight.class.getName(), Ndef.class.getName()
        }
    };

    protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.v("EditText", mEdit.getText().toString());
                    d = mEdit.getText().toString();
                }
            }
        );
        UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        UsbDeviceConnection connection;
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
        Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
        UsbDevice device = null;
        while(deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
            device = deviceIterator.next();
            String s = device.getDeviceName();
            int pid = device.getProductId();
            int did = device.getDeviceId();
            int vid = device.getVendorId();
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valueList);
            tv.setText(s + "\n" + Integer.toString(pid) + "\n" + Integer.toString(did));
        }
        connection = manager.openDevice(device);
        DataTransfer dt = new DataTransfer(device,connection);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public String Uid;

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("onNewIntent", "Action=" + intent.getAction());
        if ("android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.valueList)).setText("NFC Tag\n" + ByteArrayToHexString(intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID)));
            Uid = ByteArrayToHexString(intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Uid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (d == null){
            } else{
                a();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // disabling foreground dispatch:
        NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // creating pending intent:
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        // creating intent receiver for NFC events:
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
        filter.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        filter.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
        // enabling foreground dispatch for getting intent from NFC event:
        NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, new IntentFilter[]{filter}, this.techList);
    }

    private String ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] inarray) {
        int i, j, in;
        String[] hex = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
        String out = "";
        for (j = 0; j < inarray.length; ++j) {
            in = (int) inarray[j] & 0xff;
            i = (in >> 4) & 0x0f;
            out += hex[i];
            i = in & 0x0f;
            out += hex[i];
        }
        return out;
    }

    public void a() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), d, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        int val1 = 1;
        int val2 = 2;
        int val3 = 3;
        int val4 = 4;
        int val5 = 5;
        int val6 = 6;
        int val7 = 7;
        int val8 = 8;
        int val9 = 9;
        if (Integer.parseInt(d) == val1) {
            String f = "1758330E";
            if (f.equals(Uid)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "product 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "U will Win", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(d) == val2) {
            String f = "17574025";
            if (f.equals(Uid)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "product 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "U will Win", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(d) == val3) {
            String f = "1757F736";
            if (f.equals(Uid)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "product 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "U will Win", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(d) == val4) {
            String f = "1758330C";
            if (f.equals(Uid)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "product 4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "U will Win", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(d) == val5) {
            String f = "1757D80C";
            if (f.equals(Uid)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "product 5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "U will Win", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(d) == val6) {
            String f = "17572D00";
            if (f.equals(Uid)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "product 6", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "U will Win", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(d) == val7) {
            String f = "1757B529";
            if (f.equals(Uid)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "product 7", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "U will Win", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(d) == val8) {
            String f = "17581013";
            if (f.equals(Uid)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "product 8", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "U will Win", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(d) == val9) {
            String f = "1757D609";
            if (f.equals(Uid)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "product 9", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "U will Win", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "U will Win", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I have all the files, like:

```
SerialInputOutputManager.java
SerialInputStream.java
SerialOutputStream.java
DataTransfer.java
```

Everything is ready and complete, but I just don't know what needs to be initialized so that it sends a serial signal to Arduino.

Note: I want to send  serial signal to the Arduino from the main activity itself, from the if statements.

Here is the Arduino code:

```
char c;

void setup(){
    pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(5, LOW);
    digitalWrite(7, LOW);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()>0) {
        c = Serial.read() - '0';
        Serial.flush();
        if(c == 1){
        digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(7, LOW);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(5, LOW);
        digitalWrite(7, LOW);
      }
      if(c == 2){
        digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
        delay(4900);
        digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    }
    if(c == 3) {
      digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(7, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you connect your Android device with the Arduino to begin with?